# How can I run @BeforeEach method BEFORE @Sql script for each test case in spring boot integration test?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, integration-testing

I created a sample application here if someone wants to replicate the issue - https://github.com/jainishan/spring-boot-tryouts/blob/main/src/test/java/com/samples/sample/RepositoryTestWithJDBC.java

The above test case is pretty much what I am trying to achieve.

My use case is simple - I need to truncate all tables in a generic way before the execution of each test case in my spring boot integration tests. I am using test containers in my setup and want to run a stored procedure to clear up all tables.

I wrote a stored procedure that runs fine in the DB but doesn't execute via @Sql annotation because of delimiter issues. I was not able to solve that problem - [MYSQL procedure runs fine in DB but throwing errors while running within spring boot integration tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76374296/mysql-procedure-runs-fine-in-db-but-throwing-errors-while-running-within-spring)

Now I wrote a method to do it programatically using JDBC template - https://github.com/jainishan/spring-boot-tryouts/blob/main/src/test/java/com/samples/sample/config/BaseIntegrationTestJDBC.java#L24

I want to wire my integration tests in a way so that the method to clean up all tables run before the @Sql annotation. But the @Sql annotation always gets executed first and messes up the whole setup.

This sounds like a common requirement - to clean up tables right before each test case. I wonder how others are doing it ?

Comment: *This sounds like a common requirement - to clean up tables right before each test case. I wonder how others are doing it ?* - simple, via @SQL annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that in the following way.
First, create a JUnit extension, by implementing [`BeforeEachCallback`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.3/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/BeforeEachCallback.html), that would do the cleaning part:

```java
public class DatabaseCleanerExtension implements BeforeEachCallback {
  private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

  @Override
  public void beforeEach(ExtensionContext extensionContext) {
    if (jdbcTemplate == null) {
      jdbcTemplate = SpringExtension.getApplicationContext(extensionContext).getBean(JdbcTemplate.class);
    }
    cleanDatabase();
  }

  private void cleanDatabase() {
    jdbcTemplate.execute("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0");
    List<String> tableNames = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(
        "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = DATABASE()", String.class);
    for (String tableName : tableNames) {
      jdbcTemplate.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE " + tableName);
    }
    jdbcTemplate.execute("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1");
  }
}
```

Since extensions are not managed by Spring, `jdbcTemplate` cannot be autowired directly. However, it can be retrieved from the extension context using the line below, as explained in [Sam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56922657/10231374).

```java
SpringExtension.getApplicationContext(extensionContext).getBean(JdbcTemplate.class)
```

Then create a new class and annotate it with `@ExtendsWith(DatabaseCleanerExtension.class)`.

```java
@ExtendsWith(DatabaseCleanerExtension.class)
public class DatabaseCleaner {}
```

Finally, modify the `BaseIntegrationTestJDBC` class as shown below:

```java
@ActiveProfiles("it")
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public abstract class BaseIntegrationTestJDBC extends DatabaseCleaner {}
```

The catch is to put the `@ExtendsWith(DatabaseCleanerExtension.class)` annotation on the top of the superclass of the class annotated with `@SpringBootTest`. Otherwise, `@Sql` would still be executed before the `beforeEach` method defined in the extension.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this answer. 
Looks like, using the callback has exact same behaviour as annotation. Here is the code https://github.com/jainishan/spring-boot-tryouts/blob/main/src/test/java/com/samples/sample/RepositoryTestWithJDBCExtension.java

Comment: @ishan Okay, I've found the catch, I will update the answer.

Comment: Hi. It works fine this way. Although, it doesn't look good but it works.

Comment: I know, but at least it solves the problem. I haven't found a better solution or another solution that works yet.